# Pseudo-hash indexes for slug

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-design

I read about **pseudo-hash index** in MySQL performance optimization book, and noticed that they can help to increase performance in queries like

```
... WHERE `slug` = '$slug'
```

We can add filed `sulg_hash` in DB and index it.

After it make

```
UPDATE `table` SET `slug_hash` = CRC32(`slug`)
```

Then we just need to replace

```
... WHERE `slug` = '$slug'
```

with

```
... WHERE `slug_hash` = CRC32('$slug') AND `slug` = '$slug'
```

Because `slug_hash` field is indexed system need less time to find row we need, but that filed not uniq, so we leave `slug` = '$slug' in query.

We can index `slug` field instead of `slug_hash`, but I really hope that integer index will work much faster than text index.

Also we can replace mysql **CRC32** native function with php [**CRC32**](http://am.php.net/crc32) function.

**Problems:**

- For small tables it will work slower than simple`slug` = '$slug' query.
- In too big tables we can have many collisions so it will work slower.

Is there any issues that makes this change not interesting for performance increase?

P.S. `$slug` is escaped in start of code.

**UPDATE:** `$slug` contains not latin characters in my case. I think it will make search slower, right?

Comment: "P.S. $slug is escaped in start of code."  -- this is OK, but why don't you use query parameters? They are easy to use & protect you from accidentally allowing unescaped data in the query.

Comment: This might be usefull? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5766/when-do-hash-indexes-become-reasonable

Comment: @GabiPurcaru I just mean what we can skip discussion about security:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For small tables it will work slower than simple`slug` = '$slug'
>   query.

This won't be a problem as small tables means really fast query anyway.

> In too big tables we can have many collisions so it will work slower.

That's just the way it is. If you want to check for a full match you will have to view all characters.

For the record, MySQL supports prefix index' for character-based columns. see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). they have this index as an example

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

i prefer using prefix index' as you don't have to change your queries to also check the hash and, maybe even more important, you don't have to calculate a hash on both your script's side and inside the db. calculate hashes is not free! ;-)

Comment: You are right indexing without changing queries always better than with changing. But does 10 symbol text prefix index will work with same speed as interer with 10 numbers?

Comment: the index' are managed by mysql. don't think that mysql will save 10 utf-8 characters of your rows and do some kind of string comparison. i don't know how many characters you will need to perform best. just try it out. the more characters you include, the less tuples will be in your result (better selectivity). but also the more characters you include the larger your index becomes. large index' may not fit in memory. it's not a simple trade-off. just try out some prefix lengths.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid collisions you can use MD5 function to generate hashes, or better SHA1.
The theoretical collision rate in SHA1 is 2<sup>51</sup>, for MD5 is 2<sup>32</sup>
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5

Comment: collisions are unlikely but also unavoidable with a rising amount of data to be hashed. all hash algorithms have this problem in common. it's not a solution to just use a hash algorithm that produces longer hashes. you will have less collisions but the hash calculation will also take longer and more space when saved into the db.

Comment: MD5 and SHA1 generates alphanumeric hashes. Search in alphanumerioc index slower than in just numeric.